# How to send notifications from a phone to device connected via BLE

Tags: android, ios, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am trying to develop a companion app for a project of mine.

I want this app to relay incoming notifications on my phone to a device connected via BLE. This device will then display the text data on a screen, similar to a heads up display so that I can use it in my car and not have to go through my phone while driving (also illegal of course).

I want to know what is required for my app to be able to get notifications, and send it via BLE to the already connected device. I'd also really like to know if this can be done for an iOS app since I would prefer to end up with the final app being built for iOS. If not, android is fine for now.

This device is an ESP32 and will run its own code to execute actions when text is received.

Thank you

Comment: An iOS app can not access notifications (other than its own) for privacy reasons. You will need your Bluetooth device to connect to the ANCS service on the iOS device.

Comment: I never knew that there was a dedicated service for viewing notifications. This has already been a huge help. I am looking into it now and will try looking for things online to help me connect my device to my phone.

I am trying to connect my Android tablet to my iPhone first because I want to see the notifications coming in first however it is not bonding. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: You would need an ANCS app on your Android tablet.